# Applying node-pressure eviction for CPU resource

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, scalability

I am managing a GKE cluster that runs identical machine-learning models whose CPU usage fluctuates heavily based on the current load. Thus, I made the gap between the lower and upper limit of CPU allocation to be quite wide:

```
        resources:
          requests:
            cpu: 500m
            memory: 4000Mi
          limits:
            cpu: "4"
            memory: 6000Mi
```

The nodes themselves are using the following specifications:

```
CPU: 4 vCPU
Memory: 16GiB
```

However, there are times where pods used up all of the CPU resources in a single node without reaching their limit, and because [GKE node autoscaler operates on resource request](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/cluster-autoscaler#how_cluster_autoscaler_works) (and not the actual utilization), the cluster will not provide new node nor evict existing ones to free up resource. This condition often leads to severe throttling in the pod's performance.

The following is an example that illustrates the problem:

> Initially, the cluster only has a single node (Node A) which contains 3 pods, each using 0.5 vCPU and 4GiB memory, with a total resource utilization of 1.5 vCPU and 12 GiB memory.

> After a few hours, the two of the pods increase their resource usage from 0.5 vCPU to 1.5 vCPU each, making the total utilization to 4 vCPU and 12 GiB memory.

> Now that all of the CPU resources are in use, the pods can no longer allocate more CPU even when their loads keep on increasing, thus throttling occurs.

---

My question is: **Is there a solution to ensure that the CPU utilization of each pod expands as much as possible without being throttled?**

If possible, I want to have the cluster in the example follow this behavior:

```
cluster detects 100% CPU utilization on Node A
  -> cluster creates new node (Node B)
    -> pod(s) are evicted from Node A to Node B
```

which emulates the behavior of [node-pressure eviction](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/scheduling-eviction/node-pressure-eviction/) when the memory utilization on a node reaches its maximum capacity.